# significance level

Tags: statistical-significance

A statistician tests the null hypothesis that the proportion of
men favoring a tax reform proposal is the same as the proportion
of women. Based on sample data, the null hypothesis
is rejected at the 5% significance level. Does this imply
that the probability is at least 0.95 that the null hypothesis
is false? If not, provide a valid probability statement.

Please, can someone give me some intuition here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're very close.  It isn't exactly that there is a 95+% chance that the null hypothesis is false.  Rather, were they hypothesis actually true, there is only a 5% or less chance that the data collected (or more extreme data) could have occurred.

Comment: That means, that i could never know the probability of the null beying false, if i don't have any data right?

Comment: Right, without data you wouldn't be able to reject.